# how to compare the current date with the date in the database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I want to cancel the lock when the dates match. I have LockoutEndDateUtc field at database with DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)) - value. So tell me the correct syntax for writing this condition please.

```
if (DateTime.Now == user.LockoutEndDateUtc) { } ?
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008. It should compare DateTime.UtcNow with Date user.LockoutEndDateUtc

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- `DateTime.Now` returns the *local* time.  You should use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.
- It is nearly impossible to exactly match the current time, because typically these values are tracked with up to 7 decimal places.  Instead, you should use `>`, `<`, `>=` or `<=`.

I'm assuming a few things not stated in your question, but if you meant to lock out the user for 5 minutes, then probably you meant to set the database value with:

```
user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
```

and probably you should compare it with:

```
if (DateTime.UtcNow >= user.LockoutEndDateUtc)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have System.NullReferenceException yet at this line

Comment: Exatly, I mean to lock out user for 5 min

Comment: Well, then if your user is `null` then you'll have to give a lot more detail about how you load and save the user. You didn't tell us about that

Comment: UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        userStore.Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        UserManager<IdentityUser> manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        var user = manager.Find(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't helpful.  `UserStore`, `UserManager`, `IdentityUser`, etc. are abstractions we do not have.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will try to make my examples correct. 
But I will return to these tasks later, when it will be more clear to me how to arrange it.